# How do I position an input at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to place an `<input>` inside of a `<div>` so that when the user scrolls, the `<input>` position stays relative to the screen. I have tried `relative` and `absolute` with `position:`, but neither stay relative to the screen, they stay relative to the page size.

```css
.console {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.run {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 295px;
}
```

```html
<div class='console' height='600'>
    <input class='run' type='text' placeholder='I want this to be relative to the bottom of screen' />
</div>
```

The snippet shows the `<input>` staying at the bottom of the page; I need it to be at the bottom of the user's screen. What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: @Paulie_D I edited the question, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: When the console exceeds the height of the page, do you wish for the input to remain fixed at the bottom of the screen (with the console having a scroll bar) or move with the height of the console (with the console expanding to include all the information)?

Comment: @DKyleo I want it to remain fixed at the bottom even while scrolling

Comment: I fixed the problem and added my answer.

Comment: _“the input isn't going to the bottom of the div when I use position: relative”_ - of course it isn’t - _relative_ positioning moves an element in regard to its _own_ position it would otherwise have. A value of zero therefor does not change anything in the resulting positioning of the element.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `position: fixed;` and it worked.